# Solr Spell check not return the right collation

Tags: solr, spell-checking

I'm trying to use Solr's spell checking but the results are not working as I expected. For example, when the user's query is "amuxil" Solr returns "amul" as the first result, while "amoxil" is in the index so I expected it should be returned in the first position instead.

**solrconfig.xml**

```
<requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">5000</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">3</str>
      <!--<str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>-->
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <!-- a spellchecker built from a field of the main index -->
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">_text_</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <!-- the spellcheck distance measure used, the default is the internal levenshtein -->
      <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
      <!-- minimum accuracy needed to be considered a valid spellcheck suggestion -->
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <!-- the maximum #edits we consider when enumerating terms: can be 1 or 2 -->
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <!-- the minimum shared prefix when enumerating terms -->
      <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
      <!-- maximum number of inspections per result. -->
      <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
      <!-- minimum length of a query term to be considered for correction -->
      <int name="minQueryLength">3</int>
      <str name="comparatorClass">freq</str>
      <!-- maximum threshold of documents a query term can appear to be considered for correction
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>-->
      <!-- uncomment this to require suggestions to occur in 1% of the documents
        <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.01</float>-->
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
```

Comment: Are you sure there actually is an amoxil token in the index? You're using the direct spell checker, and the `_text_` field, which by default will have a field type with heavy processing. What is the field type you've used, and have you checked what the resulting tokens stored in the index is? (The direct spell checker uses the generated tokens directly)

Comment: *Solr returns "amul" as the first result*, does it actually returns "amoxil" at all (is it a problem of matching or weighting) ?